# Can I combine two DefaultListModels?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am trying to combine two defaultListModels in java so then I can set that model to a JList.  This program is basically adding and removing items from a shoppingCart using a GUI.  When I press the add button, it should not remove the items from the shoppingCart, but add to that List.

Here is my code from the addButton block:

```
DefaultListModel booksToAdd =  new DefaultListModel();
booksToAdd.addElement(availableBooks.getSelectedValuesList());

DefaultListModel booksAdded = new DefaultListModel();
booksAdded.addElement(shoppingCart.getModel());


// this is where it does not work.  I know I cannot just add these two, but I need
//some way to combine them.

shoppingCart.setModel(booksAdded + booksToAdd);
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is to do something like...

```
for (int index = 0; index < from.getSize(); index++) {
    to.addElement(from.getElementAt(index));
}
```

which could be wrapped in a method...

```
protected static <T> void addTo(ListModel<T> from, DefaultListModel<T> to) {
    for (int index = 0; index < from.getSize(); index++) {
        to.addElement(from.getElementAt(index));
    }
}
```

which would make it easier to use, something like...

```
DefaultListModel booksToAdd = new DefaultListModel();
DefaultListModel booksAdded = new DefaultListModel();
//...
DefaultListModel combined = new DefaultListModel();

addTo(booksToAdd, combined);
addTo(booksAdded, combined);
```

Now, if you do this sort of thing a lot, you could devise your own `ListModel` which either took one or more `ListModel`s via the constructor and added their elements to yours and/or provide an "add" method to do it.  In any case, the basic idea remains the same

Comment: Thanks that works!  Just one question, when the results come back it also gives me something along the lines of javax.swing.JList$3@43692750 in the results.  Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: The output is indicative of your using the `toString` method of object, how are you using the resulting `JList` so it prints that out